# For which vector is this matrix orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have a matrix 
$$A = \frac12 \begin{pmatrix} 1&-1&1&y_1 \\ 1&-1&-1&y_2 \\ 1&1&-1&y_3 \\ 1&1&1&y_4
\end{pmatrix} $$

in a vector space $V$ over the complex numbers $\mathbb C$. I now want to find all $y$, for which this matrix is orthognal, i.e : $A^{-1}=\omega(A^T)$, whereas $\omega$ denotes conjugation, since I am dealing with the hermitian scalar product.

So my attempt was the following: I know that the matrix is orthogonal iff the columns form a orthonormal basis of my vector space. So I decided to first make a linear system of equations, to check when the last column is orthogonal to the restly ones.

The result of that system was: $y_4 = y_4, y_1=-y_4,y_2=y_4,y_3=y_4$. This made sense to me, since I tested it out with $y_4= 1$ and it seemed to be right.

To find all vectors, I wanted to check, when the last column has a length of $1$ i.e :$$\frac{\overline y_1}2 \cdot\frac{y_1}2 + ... +\frac{\overline y_4}2 \cdot\frac{y_4}2 = 1 $$

I simplified this and substituted with the results above and I got: $$Re(y_4)^2+Im(y_4)^2 = 1$$

This however does not work... I have tried constructing such a number $y_4$ and substituted back into my matrix, but I did not get the correct result... I think it might have something to do with the last term I got above.. That condition seems to be wrong for the last column to be of length $1$, but I do not know why it is wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional condition is:

$$\frac{1}{4}(|y_1|^2+|y_2|^2+|y_3|^2+|y_4|^2)=1$$

and using your conditions you get:

$$\frac{1}{4}\cdot 4|y_1|^2=1\to|y_1|=1$$

and then any vector $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$ such that

$$(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)=(-t,t,-t,t) \text{ and } |t|=1$$

is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The orthogonality conditions give

$$
\begin{aligned}
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 &= 0 \\
-y_1 - y_2 + y_3 + y_4 &= 0 \\
y_1 - y_2 - y_3 + y_4 &= 0 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Together with the constraint that the last column must have unit length, I make the solution of these, i.e. the last column, either $(1, -1, 1, -1)^T$ or $(-1, 1, -1, 1)^T$. Substituting these values for $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4$ gives a matrix for which $A^T A = I$. These are the solutions that make the matrix orthogonal, i.e real valued. If unitary matrix is required, then solutions of the form $(\alpha, -\alpha, \alpha, -\alpha)$ are available, where $\alpha$ is complex with unit magnitude.

Comment: This is what I had so far as well. However, I want to find all values for $y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$ such that this is true.

Comment: The three orthogonality constraints mean that there is only one free variable, say $y_1 = \alpha$. Then the equations lead to solutions for $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$ of the form $(\alpha, -\alpha, \alpha, -\alpha)$. The requirement that $\| (\alpha, -\alpha, \alpha, -\alpha) / 2\| = 1$ then leads to the equation $\alpha^2=1 \Rightarrow \alpha=\pm1$. So I think that is all of the solutions.

Comment: I am just not so sure, since it says that the solutions should be complex. If I look at $\frac12 || (\alpha , - \alpha , \alpha , - \alpha) || = \frac12 * [4 \overline \alpha \alpha]$ I think there must be more solutions

Comment: Ah, ok. I was thrown by the description of the matrix as orthogonal, i.e. real, have adjusted the answer now.